# Text and loader not in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my text and "loader". I want them to be in the MIDDLE but they are centred in the top.

```css
.loader {
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.WebEntTxt {
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
<h1 class="WebEntTxt">You are entering PUBGpot! Please wait!</h1>
```

How can I get them to be in the CENTER of the screen, NOT in the TOP?

Comment: Please post a working snippet.

Comment: can i change the elements position property

Comment: Yes, you can Chandra Shekhar. I have just started programming websites and tips are welcome :)

Comment: You can use position fixed to center it both vertically and horizontally in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Since you want both text and spinner in middle, add a wrapper around both of them. Then,

Just add `position fixed` to wrapper, if you want it to position in center of the entire window. Then bring it to the center by adding `left 50%` and `top 50%`. Then you have to offset half of its original `width and height` using `translate transform`.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.loader {
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.WebEntTxt {
  color: red;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="Background" background="Background.jpg">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <h1 class="WebEntTxt">You are entering PUBGpot! Please wait!</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I could not understand what did you mean by the bigger spinner is not in the center of the screen

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The top and left with margin offset is good and not need JS for it. But with the position fixed, it not push the outer div. The loader go down, but the other elements stays on top. In this context, it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Without the need of putting *any* absolute values in the positioning - as other answers suggest-, you can use [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).

```css
.loading-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.WebEntTxt {
  color: red;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-wrapper">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <h1 class="WebEntTxt">You are entering PUBGpot! Please wait!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice technic, but is it reliable with complex html to align element..?

Comment: @TusharAcharekar Definitely. Works with any block element.

Comment: you are using `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;` that is enough to avoid this approach. it seem problematic with complex UI...!

Comment: @TusharAcharekar No it's not... Give an example?

Comment: consider you have 5 div in 1 parent div. Those 5 div appear in row with center position in desktop and  appear in column with in mobile....! this will need lot of code with your approach. your technique is not wrong but it will increase code length.

Comment: "position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;" not enough, "transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" need to be in the center of the elements.

Comment: @TusharAcharekar No it's not. Because of how translate() works, it will adjust to any width or height the parent element has.

Answer (score 0):

> Using [Flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), this is best way to align element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  
   display: flex;
   align-self: center;  
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.WebEntTxt {
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>




<body class="Background" background="Background.jpg">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <!-- <h1 class="WebEntTxt">You are entering PUBGpot! Please wait!</h1> -->

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is unlikely that OP wants `flex` on his body element.

Comment: @BramVanroy – sure, but thew OP could just as easily wrap the loader in a div and apply flex to that.

Comment: @KevinJantzer Indeed. That seems a more logical approach.